# why the current and setting time difference is varying to compare to the manual calculation?

Tags: formula, formula-field

My formula field calculation of the difference of calculation date(date/time field) and current date(date/time field).

But it is differentiated in the manual calculation answer.

```
ABS( Calculating_Date__c - NOW() )*24)
```

Above the formula is there to be used to calculate the time difference of Calculating_Date__c and current time.

But in case if the Calculating_Date__c value is 12/10/2016 6.20 AM   and the current time is 12/10/2016 7.15 PM then the difference is coming by the formula answer is 0.20 but the manually the difference is  12.55(in hours).

why this difference.and how to get the correct value.

For answers thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all
Below the answer of the question it's perfectly working for in my org.

```
((DATEVALUE( NOW()) - DATEVALUE(Calculating_Date__c))-1)*24 
+
 (24 - VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT( Calculating_Date__c  + 0.2291)),9),0,2)))
+
 VALUE(MID(RIGHT((TEXT(  NOW() + 0.2291)),9),0,2))
```

Here I used the first line to be calculated to the difference between the two dates and the second line on the formula to taking the hours to be used in the Calculating Date.

Here it's should be used only for our time line in (my time line is GMT +  5.30) so I added to the 0.2291 value in the Calculating Date and NOW() field .

```
5 hours = 5*60(minutes) = 300 + 30 (for the GMT +5.30 Minutes)= 330
So 1440(for 24 hours in minute form) = 330/1440 = 0.2291
```

Thank You,Mohan

Answer (score 1):

Time values in Salesforce are stored in GMT while NOW() is returning time in the user's timezone. Get your org Default Time Zone difference and adjust your result, e.g. for my org it's CST (Chicago) GMT -5, so formula would look like `ABS( Calculating_Date__c - NOW() )*24) - 5`

Comment: My time zone GMT + 5.30. But also I get wrong answer in my manual calculating answer to compared to the formula answer to make the changes in my formula as like in your formula.

Comment: do u need a difference in hours, not in a day fractions?

Comment: @MohanRaj I just edited the formula - it was incorrect, in your case (GMT +5:30) it should be `ABS( Calculating_Date__c - NOW() )*24) + 5.5`

Comment: sorry sir, This answer is also providing the wrong answer. For example My Calculating Date is 10.05 PM and NOW() value is 10.35 AM here the difference is in only 12.30 hours but the answer of the formula returns is 23.49 in  hours.I am also to fix the problem in this time difference bug if you find it please send me.Thank you Mohan.

Comment: I forget to enteered the date value My calculating date value in  the test time is 10/14/2016 for the both Calculating Date and NOW() then the time value is difference by Calculating Date and NOW() is 10.05PM and 10.35AM respectively and the formula output is 23.49 hours but the actual difference only 12.30 hours only.